# Problems using landsat-util

Tags: python, landsat, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install `landsat-util` in an Ubuntu AWS instance. First, I created a Python 2.7 environment called `landsat_py2` to avoid conflicts and the installation process seems to be fine. Nonetheless, when I run the help: `landsat -h`, the following appear:

```py
(landsat_py2) imendieta@wef-oceans:~$ landsat -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/imendieta/.conda/envs/landsat_py2/bin/landsat", line 7, in <module>
    from landsat.landsat import __main__
  File "/home/imendieta/.conda/envs/landsat_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/landsat/landsat.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .image import Simple, PanSharpen, FileDoesNotExist
  File "/home/imendieta/.conda/envs/landsat_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/landsat/image.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rasterio
  File "/home/imendieta/.conda/envs/landsat_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterio-0.32.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rasterio/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import eval_window, window_shape, window_index
ImportError: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[UPDATE: After running `$ conda install -c conda-forge gdal rasterio jpeg=8d matplotlib=1.5.1` the problem resolves and `Landsat-util` runs flawlessly.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and the following worked for me:

> conda install -c conda-forge gdal rasterio jpeg=8d

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but errors keep coming (I update the question with the new errors). I have already issue the question in the GitHub repo. `matplotlib` version is kind of bugging. The same errors appear when I try in my local Mac machine.

Comment: Finally I could install the utility. I added `matplotlib=1.5.1` to the installation of the other packages inside the virtual environment with Python 3.5